# Супертипы и подтипы в typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Делаю приложение на react/typescript.
В приложении есть свой ui-kit с переиспользуемыми компонентами - Select, Input, Button и тд. И ,соответсвенно, разные потребители этих компонентов со своими типами.

Не получается затипизировать Select.
Упрощенный пример - https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-albattani-h95cfj

Тип у пропа selectedItem:

```
type SelectedItem = { value: string | number; label?: string; };
```

А у пропа onChange:

```
(option: SelectedItem) => void
```

Там, где используется этот компонент, я хочу прокинуть в проп selectedItem такой тип

```
type City = { value: string; label: string }
```

А в проп onChange:

```
 (city: City) => void
```

Я ожидаю, что типы описанные в компоненте Select будут являться **супертипами**, тогда:

1. Тип City будет **подтипом** для SelectedItem
2. Тип (city: City) => void будет **подтипом** для (option: SelectedItem) => void

Первый пункт срабатывает, а второй почему то нет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как будто бы ts считает (city: City) => void супертипом, а тип (option: SelectedItem) => void подтипом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Компонент ожидает функцию, которая может принимать как `number` так и `string`.

Ты передаешь функцию, которая может принимать только `string`. Поэтому ее нельзя использовать.

---

На примере:

есть тип

```
type P = string | number;
```

есть тип функции

```
type Callback = (param: P) => void;
```

И переменная с этим типом: `var cb: Callback`.

предположим, что в эту переменную можно записать функцию принимающую только `string`

```
var cb:Callback = (p:string) => console.log(p.length);
```

В этом случае возникает проблема с вызовом `cb(10)`.

1. тип `Callback` - разрешает такой вызов, потому что тип параметра может быть либо строкой либо числом.
2. Присвоенная функция - не разрешает, так как требует, чтобы параметр был **только** строкой.

Как следствие, само присваивание тоже не разрешено.

Comment: Именно так. Я ожидаю, что это должно работать, потому что:
**string является подмножеством string | number**.
Но ts в данном случае почему то считает в обратную сторону - пытается понять: **является ли string | number подмножеством string**
и конечно же падает с ошибкой

Comment: @EgorG ты не в ту сторону думаешь.

Comment: @EgorG, обновил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо, я разобрался

Answer (score 0):

Ты даже не все параметры передал, и вообще фигня в типах. Пример-то надо было до нормального состояния сначала довести, а потом спрашивать.

В общем, у меня получилось такое. Но если бы ты не пропустил параметр `options`, вероятно, могло бы и что-то более простое заработать, но мне теперь лень.

https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-currying-t8pi8w?file=/src/ui-kit/Select.tsx

```
export type SelectedItem<T extends number | string> = {
  value: T;
  label?: string;
};

type SelectProps<T extends SelectedItem<any>> = {
  selectedItem: T;
  onChange: (opt: T) => void;
  options: T[];
};

export function Select<T extends SelectedItem<any>>({ selectedItem, onChange, options }: SelectProps<T>) {
  return null;
}
```

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";
import { Select } from "./ui-kit/Select";

type City = { value: string; label: string };

const cities: City[] = [];

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState<City>({
    value: "1",
    label: "Moscow"
  });

  const handleChange = (opt: City) => {
    setValue(opt);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Select onChange={handleChange} selectedItem={value} options={cities} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, решение с any не подходит